# How to share internet via wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, kde, hotspot, kde-plasma-5

I have latest KDE Neon, with Plasma 5 desktop.
For sharing my wired internet to other devices via wifi, I have followed this easy guide:
[Create Wi-fi Hotspot Using KDE Plasma 5](https://arief-jr.blogspot.com.es/2016/03/create-wi-fi-hotspot-shared-using-kde.html), but with an Android smartphone, I cannot see the new created SSID.

With this Android phone, I have connected successfully with many wifi networks.  I don't suspect on it.

How can I diagnose the problem?
Misconfiguration, KDE bug, wifi driver bug or problem with the card manufacturer?.

**UPDATE**

Result of `ip addr show` command:

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    ....
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:92:9c:01:37:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Number 1 is loopback, number 2 is ethernet and number 3 is regular wifi, and is unconnected.  But wifi hotspot doesn't appear.

Comment: result of "ip addr show" command ?

Comment: ```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: ...
2: enp4s0: ...
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:92:9c:01:37:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: updated description

Comment: Is this still an issue? I have the same OS as well so I can test this in the next few days

Comment: yes, I'm using KDE Neon based on Ubuntu 16.04.  Thanks.